# Azure Pipeline Creating blank folder for drop Artifact with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines

In the Azure Build Pipeline. I have a powershell task that creates a folder

`New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\changedfiles`

And populate it by using this line of code if we have $file.

`Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\changedfiles`

The problem is when the there is no item to be input in the folder `changesfiles`, there
are no `changesfiles` folder being created. Would need it to be in there for the release pipeline.

I have a Copy Artifact to Machine Server target and it will try to check for that specific
folder from the `drop` artifact. But it will throw an error because the folder is not created when there is no files in it.

My goal is to just to make sure that the Copy Artifact not to return any error.

[image: If there is a file]

[image: Without File in the changedfiles folder]

[image: I want to Prevent this]

If there is some files I added to the changesfiles folder then I will have this

[image]

If there I did not add anything to it this is the result, but ofcourse there is a changes on the repository that indicates 1 because I have changed the yml file. Which I didn't want to put in the changedfiles folder. hence the changedfiles folder is blank and it will not be on the 'drop' artifact as indicated in my previous screen shot.

[image]

Comment: There is no artifact at all I assume is there?

Comment: What other tasks are you using in the pipeline? For example CopyFiles@2 ?

Comment: May I know where you want to copy the artifacts? And what files you want to put in drop? You can use a task named "Publish build artifacts" to publish files to artifacts/drop folder.

Comment: @promicro Updated my Question. There is some files, but the second image indicates that there is no "Blank Folder" changedfiles if I don't add anything to it.

Comment: @DorisLv I will put it in a specific path on the server which everything works fine. The issue is there is an error in the release pipeline because there is no folder changedfiles being generated if there is no files in the staging folder of the build. The pipeline is working... I just don't want to see this error.

Comment: @Aizen can you share some more info about the pipeline? Do you have a log that the powershell script has successfully ran? I have curious if the folder is cleaned at some point

Comment: @promicro added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some tests and the problem seems to be in the PublishBuildArtifacts task. It simply cannot copy empty folders. I have looked in [the source code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/commit/350655f82f48d9ece04b730a455def7a8f5bd178), and this could easily be a RoboCopy thing.

I can however offer you two options to overcome this issue.

### 1

Add a place holder file in your folder with this single line of PowerShell:

`New-Item -Name .placeholder -ItemType File  -Path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/changedfiles`

**The result:**
[image: placeholder in artifact]

### 2

Another option is to use the [StoreAsTar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-build-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops#inputs) option in the PublishBuildArtifacts task:
`StoreAsTar: true`

This will TAR the artifact folder and preserves the empty folder:
[image: TAR example]

Comment: Marking as the correct Answer. As there is an alternative and Explanation for the Source Code.

Comment: You need to put $ on the Build.Artifacts

Comment: @Aizen thanks, I corrected the answer. No clue where the $ went :-)